# php obtain file stream to a section of a larger file stream

Tags: php, filestream

Might seem strange, but I have a huge file and I need to process it and obtain ranges of the stream and treat them like streams themselves which I can then maybe recursively obtain a smaller stream from.

The problem I'm trying to avoid is copying huge amounts of data into memory, say you have a 4GB XML file, I would like to open it with a file stream.

I can search in the stream for a particular token and then continue to search for a terminating token.  This range of bytes might be 2GB in size, which means to host it in a variable is not practical.

I could write a wrapper around the "variable" and any attempt to read or write to it, I would control, for example, say I want to search that variable itself for another token/terminator, then return another stream representing that range of bytes too.

So all of this would be like holding offset+range locations within the huge file without copying any of the data into the memory, I'd just have to store the start/stop byte ranges for each "variable" and then when I'm totally sure I want to read the data into a variable, I can export it.

This would sidestep the problem of storing huge amounts of data in memory and I'm aware of the performance problems, I'd rather a solution which worked than a solution which used up gigabytes of memory

Comment: `fopen()`, `fread()`, ...? http://php.net/filesystem

Comment: You can read the following article http://www.gregfreeman.org/2013/processing-data-with-php-using-stdin-and-piping/

Comment: I think you miss the point.  I want to open a stream and read from byte 0 to byte X (eg: 4gb) and find a token, it is at point 1.2gb into the stream, then search for another token and find it at 1.8gb into the stream, meaning there is a chunk of the stream 0.6gb long, I want to return a handle to this byte range, that reading byte 0 from this stream, will read from 1.2gb into the original stream and the end byte in the stream is 0.6gb, at the end, it's like I want to open a file and the handle represents the entire file, but open a stream to a subrange of bytes and behave like a new stream